# How to interweave shell prompts and child process output, ideally only using std?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to re-create my OS projects into Rust, and I am currently having a stylistic issue, where I am trying to create a very simple shell, where it takes an input and executes a command. My issue is that, when using:

```
print!("tsh> ");
let mut input: String = String::new();
let _ = io::stdout().flush(); // allows to print then stdinio::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Error: Expected input");
```

Afterwards, when the command executes, the output looks something like this:

```
tsh> ls .
tsh> Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml     src  target
```

Where I would input below the second `tsh>..`

I would very much prefer to ONLY use the standard library where I am able to, just because it's a fun challenge, and it seems like what I should do since the original is based on the C++ standard library. Here's a minimal version of the code:

```
use std::io::{self,Write};
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    loop {
        print!("tsh> ");
        let mut input: String = String::new();
        let _ = io::stdout().flush(); // allows to print then stdin
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Error: Expected input");
        
        if &input != "\n" {
            let tokens: Vec<&str> = input.split_whitespace().collect();
            let output = Command::new(tokens[0].to_string())
                .arg(tokens[1..].join(" "))
                .spawn()
                .expect("Error: Failed to execute command");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child processes execute in parallel with your program. Add a call to [`wait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) to wait for them to finish before showing the next prompt.

```rust
let _exit_status = Command::new(tokens[0].to_string())
    .arg(tokens[1..].join(" "))
    .spawn()
    .expect("Error: Failed to execute command")
    .wait()
    .expect("Error: Failed to execute command");
```